# Agregar el mismo producto con diferentes medidas usando PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

quisiera saber si es posible agregar el mismo producto con diferentes medidas a mi tabla donde realizo las ventas, los pongo en contexto estoy realizando un sistema de venta e inventarios utilizando php el problema es que mi docente me dijo que cambiara la forma de vender las calaminas haciendo que cada una de estas se puedan vender por diferentes medidas.
el sistema lo realice de la siguiente manera:

[image: Esta es la vista del módulo de venta]
[image: Este modal es donde busco y agrego el producto]
[image: Una vez agregado se mostrara el siguiente modal donde agrego las medidas]
[image: Y el producto se agrega a la tabla pero obviamente no puedo agregar otra vez el mismo producto]

El código de la vista de venta es el siguiente, donde los datos del producto están almacenados en el array de la variable de sesión datos-producto:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <p class="text-center roboto-medium">AGREGAR CLIENTE Y PRODUCTOS</p>
        <p class="text-center">
            <?php if (empty($_SESSION['datos_cliente'])) { ?>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalCliente"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> &nbsp; Agregar cliente</button>
            <?php } ?>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalItem"><i class="fas fa-box-open"></i> &nbsp; Agregar Producto</button>
        </p>
        
        <div>
            <span class="roboto-medium">CLIENTE:</span>
            <?php if (empty($_SESSION['datos_cliente'])) { ?>
            <span class="text-danger">&nbsp; <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Seleccione un cliente</span>
        <?php }else{ ?>
            <form class="FormularioAjax" action="<?php echo SERVERURL; ?>ajax/ventaAjax.php" method="POST" data-form="loans" style="display: inline-block !important;">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_eliminar_cliente" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['datos_cliente']['ID']; ?>">
                <?php echo $_SESSION['datos_cliente']['Nombre']." ".$_SESSION['datos_cliente']['Apellido']."(".$_SESSION['datos_cliente']['DNI'].")"; ?>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-user-times"></i></button>
            </form>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-dark table-sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="text-center roboto-medium">
                        <th>PRODUCTO</th>
                        <th>TIPO</th>
                        <th>CANTIDAD</th>
                        <th>UNIDAD</th>
                        <th>DESCUENTO</th>
                        <th>MEDIDA</th>
                        <th>PRECIO UNITARIO</th>
                        <th>PRECIO NORMAL</th>
                        <th>SUBTOTAL</th>
                        <th>COLOR</th>
                        <th>ELIMINAR</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                        if (isset($_SESSION['datos_producto']) && count($_SESSION['datos_producto'])>=1) {
                            $_SESSION['venta_total']=0;
                            $_SESSION['venta_producto']=0;

                            foreach ($_SESSION['datos_producto'] as $productos) {
                                $espesor=$productos['Lamina']*$productos['Metro'];
                                $cantidad=$productos['Cantidad']+$espesor;
                                $precio=$cantidad*$productos['Precio'];
                                $descuento=$precio-($precio*$productos['Descuento']/100);
                                $subtotal=$descuento;
                                $subtotal=number_format($subtotal,2,'.','');
                     ?>
                    <tr class="text-center" >
                        <td><?php echo $productos['Nombre']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $productos['Tipo']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $cantidad; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $productos['Medida']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $productos['Descuento'].PORCENTAJE; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $productos['Lamina']." X ".$productos['Metro']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $productos['Precio'].MONEDA; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $precio.MONEDA; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $subtotal.MONEDA; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $productos['Detalle']; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <form class="FormularioAjax" action="<?php echo SERVERURL; ?>ajax/ventaAjax.php" method="POST" data-form="loans" autocomplete="off">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id_eliminar_producto" value="<?php echo $productos['ID'] ?>">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">
                                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                            $_SESSION['venta_total']+=$subtotal;
                            $_SESSION['venta_producto']+=$cantidad;

                             }

                 ?>
                    <tr class="text-center bg-light">
                        <td><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
                        <td><strong><?php echo $_SESSION['venta_producto']; ?> productos</strong></td>
                        <td colspan="6"></td>
                        <td><strong><?php echo number_format($_SESSION['venta_total'],2,'.','').MONEDA; ?></strong></td>
                        <td colspan="2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php }else{
                            $_SESSION['venta_total']=0;
                            $_SESSION['venta_producto']=0;
                     ?>
                    <tr class="text-center" >
                        <td colspan="11">No seleccionaste un producto</td>
                        
                    </tr>

                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

El controlador para agregar el producto es el siguiente, como podrán notar los datos del producto se almacenan en un array con una variable de sesión datos-producto:

```
public function agregar_producto_venta_controlador(){
        /* Recuperando id del producto */
        $id=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['id_agregar_item']);

        /* comprobando producto en la bd */
        $check_producto=mainModel::ejecutar_consulta_simple("SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_id='$id' AND item_estado='Habilitado'");
        if ($check_producto->rowCount()<=0) {
            $alerta=[
                "Alerta"=>"simple",
                "Titulo"=>"Ocurrió un error inesperado",
                "Texto"=>"No se pudo seleccionar el producto, por favor intente nuevamente",
                "Tipo"=>"error"
            ];
            echo json_encode($alerta);
            exit();
        }else{
            $campos=$check_producto->fetch();
        }

        $tipo=mainModel::ejecutar_consulta_simple("SELECT tipo_nombre FROM tipo WHERE tipo_id=".$campos['tipo_id']."");
        if ($tipo->rowCount()<=0) {
            $alerta=[
                "Alerta"=>"simple",
                "Titulo"=>"Ocurrió un error inesperado",
                "Texto"=>"No se pudo seleccionar el tipo, por favor intente nuevamente",
                "Tipo"=>"error"
            ];
            echo json_encode($alerta);
            exit();
        }else{
            $tipos=$tipo->fetch();
        }

        $medida=mainModel::ejecutar_consulta_simple("SELECT medida_nombre FROM medida WHERE medida_id=".$campos['id_medida']."");
        if ($medida->rowCount()<=0) {
            $alerta=[
                "Alerta"=>"simple",
                "Titulo"=>"Ocurrió un error inesperado",
                "Texto"=>"No se pudo seleccionar la unidad de medida, por favor intente nuevamente",
                "Tipo"=>"error"
            ];
            echo json_encode($alerta);
            exit();
        }else{
            $medidas=$medida->fetch();
        }

        /* recuperando detalles de la venta */
        
        $cantidad=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['detalle_cantidad']);
        $descuento=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['detalle_descuento']);
        $lamina=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['detalle_laminas']);
        $metro=mainModel::limpiar_cadena($_POST['detalle_metros']);
        
        /*== comprobar campos vacios ==*/
        if($cantidad==""){
            $alerta=[
                "Alerta"=>"simple",
                "Titulo"=>"Ocurrió un error inesperado",
                "Texto"=>"No has llenado todos los campos que son obligatorios",
                "Tipo"=>"error"
            ];
            echo json_encode($alerta);
            exit();
        }

        /*== Verificando integridad de los datos ==*/
        if(mainModel::verificar_datos("[0-9.]{1,10}",$cantidad)){
            $alerta=[
                "Alerta"=>"simple",
                "Titulo"=>"Ocurrió un error inesperado",
                "Texto"=>"La cantidad no coincide con el formato solicitado",
                "Tipo"=>"error"
            ];
            echo json_encode($alerta);
            exit();
        }

        if ($cantidad>$campos['item_stock']) {
            $alerta=[
                "Alerta"=>"simple",
                "Titulo"=>"Ocurrió un error inesperado",
                "Texto"=>"La cantidad no puede ser mayor a la cantidad del producto o puede que ya no se disponga de las existencias del producto, verifique la existencias del producto",
                "Tipo"=>"error"
            ];
            echo json_encode($alerta);
            exit();
        }
        session_start(['name'=>'SPM']);
        if (empty($_SESSION['datos_producto'][$id])) {
            $_SESSION['datos_producto'][$id]=[
                "ID"=>$campos['item_id'],
                "Codigo"=>$campos['item_codigo'],
                "Nombre"=>$campos['item_nombre'],
                "Detalle"=>$campos['item_detalle'],
                "Precio"=>$campos['item_precio'],
                "Lamina"=>$lamina,
                "Metro"=>$metro,
                "Tipo"=>$tipos['tipo_nombre'],
                "Medida"=>$medidas['medida_nombre'],
                "Cantidad"=>$cantidad,
                "Descuento"=>$descuento
            ];
            $alerta=[
                "Alerta"=>"recargar",
                "Titulo"=>"Producto agregado",
                "Texto"=>"el producto fue agregado",
                "Tipo"=>"success"
            ];
            echo json_encode($alerta);
            exit();
        }else{
            $alerta=[
                "Alerta"=>"simple",
                "Titulo"=>"Ocurrió un error inesperado",
                "Texto"=>"El producto que intenta agregar ya se encuentra seleccionado",
                "Tipo"=>"error"
            ];
            echo json_encode($alerta);
            exit();
        }
        
    }
```

Este es el controlador de la venta donde envío lo datos al modelo para que se almacene a la base de datos.

```
/* Generando código Venta */
        $correlativo=mainModel::ejecutar_consulta_simple("SELECT venta_id FROM venta");
        $correlativo=($correlativo->rowCount())+1;
        $codigo=mainModel::generar_codigo_aleatorio("CP",7,$correlativo);
        $datos_venta_reg=[
            "Codigo"=>$codigo,
            "FechaInicio"=>$fecha_inicio,
            "HoraInicio"=>$hora_inicio,
            "FechaFinal"=>$fecha_final,
            "HoraFinal"=>$hora_final,
            "Cantidad"=>$_SESSION['venta_producto'],
            "Total"=>$total_prestamo,
            "Pagado"=>$total_pagado,
            "Estado"=>$estado,
            "Observacion"=>$observacion,
            "Usuario"=>$_SESSION['id_spm'],
            "Cliente"=>$_SESSION['datos_cliente']['ID'],
            "Caja"=>$caja,
        ];

        /* Agregar venta */
        $agregar_venta=ventaModelo::agregar_venta_modelo($datos_venta_reg);

        if ($agregar_venta->rowCount()!=1) {
            $alerta=[
                "Alerta"=>"simple",
                "Titulo"=>"Ocurrió un error inesperado",
                "Texto"=>"No se pudo registrar la venta, por favor intente nuevamente",
                "Tipo"=>"error"
            ];
            echo json_encode($alerta);
            exit();
        }


        /* Agregar pago */

        if ($total_pagado>0) {
            $datos_pago_reg=[
                "Total"=>$total_pagado,
                "Fecha"=>$fecha_inicio,
                "Codigo"=>$codigo
            ];
            $agregar_pago=ventaModelo::agregar_venta_modelo($datos_pago_reg);

            if ($agregar_pago->rowCount()!=1) {
                ventaModelo::eliminar_venta_modelo($codigo,"Venta");
                $alerta=[
                    "Alerta"=>"simple",
                    "Titulo"=>"Ocurrió un error inesperado",
                    "Texto"=>"No se pudo registrar la venta, por favor intente nuevamente",
                    "Tipo"=>"error"
                ];
                echo json_encode($alerta);
                exit();
            }
        }


        /* Agregar detalle */
        $errores_detalle=0;

        foreach ($_SESSION['datos_producto'] as $productos) {


            /* comprobando producto en la bd */
        $check_producto=mainModel::ejecutar_consulta_simple("SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_id=".$productos['ID']." AND item_estado='Habilitado'");
        if ($check_producto->rowCount()<=0) {
            $alerta=[
                "Alerta"=>"simple",
                "Titulo"=>"Ocurrió un error inesperado",
                "Texto"=>"No se pudo seleccionar el producto, por favor intente nuevamente",
                "Tipo"=>"error"
            ];
            echo json_encode($alerta);
            exit();
        }else{
            $campos=$check_producto->fetch();
        }
            /*------ RESTAR EXISTENCIAS DEL PRODUCTO------------- */
            $espesores=$productos['Lamina']*$productos['Metro'];
            $cantidades=$productos['Cantidad']+$espesores;
            $stocksum=$campos['item_stock']-$cantidades;
            $stocksum=number_format(($stocksum),2,'.','');
            $datos_stock_detalle_up=[
                    "Stock"=>$stocksum,
                    "ID"=>$campos['item_id']
                ];
                prestamoModelo::actualizar_stock_producto_modelo($datos_stock_detalle_up);
            
            $descripcion=$productos['Codigo']." ".$productos['Nombre'];
            $espesor=$productos['Lamina']*$productos['Metro'];
            $cantidad=$productos['Cantidad']+$espesor;
            $lamina=$productos['Lamina'];
            $metro=$productos['Metro'];
            $precio=$productos['Precio'];
            $tipo=$productos['Tipo'];
            $medida=$productos['Medida'];
            $detalle=$productos['Detalle'];
            $datos_detalle_reg=[
                "Cantidad"=>$cantidad,
                "Descuento"=>$productos['Descuento'],
                "Descripcion"=>$descripcion,
                "Precio"=>$precio,
                "Lamina"=>$lamina,
                "Metro"=>$metro,
                "Tipo"=>$tipo,
                "Medida"=>$medida,
                "Detalle"=>$detalle,
                "Prestamo"=>$codigo,
                "Item"=>$productos['ID']

            ];

            $agregar_detalle=ventaModelo::agregar_detalle_modelo($datos_detalle_reg);

            if ($agregar_detalle->rowCount()!=1) {
                $errores_detalle=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($errores_detalle==0) {
            unset($_SESSION['datos_cliente']);
            unset($_SESSION['datos_producto']);
            $alerta=[
                    "Alerta"=>"recargar",
                    "Titulo"=>"Venta Registrada",
                    "Texto"=>"Los datos de la venta han sido Registrados ",
                    "Tipo"=>"success"
                ];
        }else{
            ventaModelo::eliminar_venta_modelo($codigo,"Detalle");
            ventaModelo::eliminar_venta_modelo($codigo,"Pago");
            ventaModelo::eliminar_venta_modelo($codigo,"Venta");
                $alerta=[
                    "Alerta"=>"simple",
                    "Titulo"=>"Ocurrió un error inesperado",
                    "Texto"=>"No se pudo registrar la venta, por favor intente nuevamente",
                    "Tipo"=>"error"
                ];
        }
        echo json_encode($alerta);

    }
```

Y por ultimo este es el modelo de la venta donde se encuentran las consultas, los datos del producto se almacenan en una tabla llamada "detalle" el cual esta relacionada con mi tabla "venta" mediante el código de venta:

```
/*--------- Modelo agregar venta ---------*/
    protected static function agregar_venta_modelo($datos){
        $sql=mainModel::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO venta(venta_codigo,venta_fecha_inicio,venta_hora_inicio,venta_fecha_final,venta_hora_final,venta_cantidad,venta_total,venta_pagado,venta_estado,venta_observacion,usuario_id,cliente_id,caja_id) VALUES(:Codigo,:FechaInicio,:HoraInicio,:FechaFinal,:HoraFinal,:Cantidad,:Total,:Pagado,:Estado,:Observacion,:Usuario,:Cliente,:Caja)");

            $sql->bindParam(":Codigo",$datos['Codigo']);
            $sql->bindParam(":FechaInicio",$datos['FechaInicio']);
            $sql->bindParam(":HoraInicio",$datos['HoraInicio']);
            $sql->bindParam(":FechaFinal",$datos['FechaFinal']);
            $sql->bindParam(":HoraFinal",$datos['HoraFinal']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Cantidad",$datos['Cantidad']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Total",$datos['Total']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Pagado",$datos['Pagado']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Estado",$datos['Estado']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Observacion",$datos['Observacion']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Usuario",$datos['Usuario']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Cliente",$datos['Cliente']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Caja",$datos['Caja']);
            $sql->execute();

            return $sql;
    }

    /*--------- Modelo agregar detalle ---------*/
    protected static function agregar_detalle_modelo($datos){
        $sql=mainModel::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO detalle(detalle_cantidad,detalle_descuento,detalle_descripcion,detalle_item_precio,detalle_lamina,detalle_metro,detalle_item_tipo,detalle_item_medida,detalle_item_detalle,venta_codigo,item_id) VALUES(:Cantidad,:Descuento,:Descripcion,:Precio,:Lamina,:Metro,:Tipo,:Medida,:Detalle,:Venta,:Item)");

            $sql->bindParam(":Cantidad",$datos['Cantidad']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Descuento",$datos['Descuento']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Descripcion",$datos['Descripcion']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Precio",$datos['Precio']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Lamina",$datos['Lamina']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Metro",$datos['Metro']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Tipo",$datos['Tipo']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Medida",$datos['Medida']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Detalle",$datos['Detalle']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Venta",$datos['Venta']);
            $sql->bindParam(":Item",$datos['Item']);
            $sql->execute();

            return $sql;
    }
```

Lo que yo quiero lograr es poder agregar el mismo producto con diferentes medidas a mi tabla donde realizo las ventas, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: si no vamos a la normalizacion de tablas explica que no debes repetir un producto si algo cambia por lo que medidas debe tener su tabla aparte dado que el nombre es el mismo, los demas campos deben estar en otra tabla al igual que el tipo, esto hara mas fasil la busqueda de tipo y produto y te permite hacer joins para buscar diferentes tamanos!

Comment: deberias poner tu modelo relacional o entidad-relacion, e indicanos si estas dispuesto a cambiar ese diseño o no. @Terrazas Gustavo